# get from rally graph

Tags: java, rest, jersey, rally

I'm developing a Dynamic web Project in **java**, and the goal is upon click on button to fetch the "ITERATION BURNDOWN" graph from https://rally1.rallydev.com.
my question is do i have to know the rally api in order to get this content or just to go to the appropriate url and search there the graph?
i login successfully to the rally (used this link for the login: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-automate-login-a-website-java-example/).
after i login successfully i couldn't get the url with the graph. it's just returning the landing page content.

pls help,
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you refer to IterationBurndown on Reports>Reports page, which is served by a legacy analytics engine.

To get the appropriate URL you may need to install IterationBurndown report wrapped in an app from AppCatalog on a custom page in Rally. I cannot confirm a java scenario, but the URL of that custom page can be used with javascript, by making an html file with this custom page embedded using iframe, for example:

```
iframe.src = "https://rally1.rallydev.com/#/12345d/custom/6789";
```

The steps are:

- create a  [custom page](https://help.rallydev.com/create-custom-pages)
- install IterationBurndown report from the [AppCatalog](https://help.rallydev.com/app-catalog) as an app.

At least in the javascript app case, the URL to IterationBurndown on Reports page will not work for this purpose, hence the extra step of using a custom page.

When you say that you get a landing page, I am not sure if you are referring to login page or home page. If it is the former, it means authentication has not been handled. Legacy IterationBurndown report wrapped in an app will not work with newer [ApiKey](https://help.rallydev.com/rally-application-manager). That's too bad because ApiKey, unlike LoginKey, works with Java as well, unlike the legacy [LoginKey](https://github.com/RallyTools/Login-Component-Example) which works in the browser (with html/javascript apps) only.